# How to print contents of buffer in C?

Tags: c, printf, fwrite, fread, cs50

C newbie here working on problem set 4 of CS50, where you are given a memory card to recover 50 jpeg files.

I'm trying to read the raw data 512 bytes at a time, but I would like to know how to I can print the contents of each 512 byte block ?

My method of using `fwrite` doesn't seem to be printing anything in this instance:

```
fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr);

fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, stdout);
```

Rest of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure only 1 command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover infile");
        return 1;
    }

    // Remember filename
    char *infile = argv[1];


    // Open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // Create buffer to store 8 bits 512 times
    uint8_t buffer[512];

    fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr);

    fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, stdout);

    // Close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you attempt to print (or write directly, more accurately) the contents of arbitrary binary data, most of it probably isn't printable. You'll only see those bytes that have an ASCII viewable representation. Maybe you want a hex dump? In that case, you'd convert each byte to a two-character ASCII string that represent the two hex digits of the byte.

Comment: This exercise comes up quite often as can be seen by searching "CS50 memory card recover jpeg file stackoverflow C".

Comment: When using `fread` you should not rely on the file size being an exact multiple of the buffer size (although it may be true in the example). Always get the number of elements read with such as `size_t count = fread(buffer, 1, 512, inptr);` (notice the swapped arguments 2 and 3). And then, assuming a more appropriate output context, `fwrite(buffer, 1, count, outptr);`. Finally you can use `count` to control a read/write loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JPEG file contains binary data, so you can't print it the same way you would  print a string.

What you probably want is to print the hex value of each byte you've read.  You can do that as follows:

```
for (i=0; i<512; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
    if ((i+1)%16 == 0) printf("\n");
}
```

This will print each byte in hex, with 16 bytes written per line.

Comment: A lot of POSIX-type distributions have [`hexdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump&sektion=1) as well, which is similar.

Comment: If we're not assuming `buffer` to be `unsigned char`, it's a good idea to either cast it or mask to 8-bit in the `printf()` call, otherwise the default conversion to `int` tends to deliver wide surprises.

Comment: Thanks! Though I must ask, what is `%02x`?

Comment: @doctopus The `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int` and prints it as hexadecimal.  The field width of `2` means to print in a field 2 characters wide, and the `0` flag means to pad the value on the left with zeros.